# Using types in a record to enforce its value in typescript

Tags: typescript

Given that I have the following types:

```
export type AnalyticsEventButtonClicked = {
  type: 'AnalyticsEventButtonClicked',
  payload: {
    label: string;
  }
};

export type AnalyticsEventTextChanged = {
  type: 'AnalyticsEventTextChanged',
  payload: {
    value: string;
  }
};

export type AnalyticsEvents = 
  | AnalyticsEventButtonClicked
  | AnalyticsEventTextChanged;
```

I want to be able to create a `Record` which will take both of these analytics events and specifically know what the payload should be based on its key. For example:

```
export const handleAnalytics: Record<AnalyticsEvents['type'], (???['payload']) => string> = {
  AnalyticsEventButtonClicked: ({ label }) => { return `Label: ${label}`; },
  AnalyticsEventTextChanged: ({ value }) => { return `Value: ${value}`; },
};
```

I am trying to find out what to replace `???` with in order to ensure the parameters of the anonymous callback function matches the payload that corresponds to the key in the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a Record you will need to make the mapped type yourself so you can have access to the key being used:

```
export const handleAnalytics: {
    [K in AnalyticsEvents["type"]]: (params: Extract<AnalyticsEvents, { type: K }>["payload"]) => string;
}
```

We use Extract to get the member of the union whose type is K, then get their payload.

Comment: I think you just need to add a param slot on the callback ->  `(params: Extract<Analytics.......`